# My headers are being changed after I set them?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cors

I have a `Rails` server running and am making an ajax call with `jQuery`.  Here is my `ajax` call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://local.diabeticconnect:3001/posts',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
}, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

When I look at the `headers` in my chrome dev tools, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` has been completely removed.  What is `jQuery` not setting these `headers`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set this header by yourself, this basically will be set from the server when it allows requests from all origins.